# Query to update an image in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

I have an image data in a .txt file which is of the format 0xFFD8FFE000104A.... I would like to update an exsisting image stored in a table whose datatype is of Image, with the data I have in my .txt.

I tried with the normal UPDATE statement. The data sets updated, however the updated image does not get displayed in my application. This was the query:

```
update Images set picture=0xFFD8FFE...
where Id=167
```

Kindly let me know the SQL query to make this possible. I use SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which kind of field is _picture_? What does it mean _the updated image does not get displayed in my application_? How do you retrieve it and show in your form? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

[Inserting or Updating an Image File Using OPENROWSET and BULK](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SQLServer/0100__Data-Types/InsertingorUpdatinganImageFileUsingOPENROWSETandBULK.htm)